# Having trouble building a Script to look up Places in Google's API and return relevant data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I'm working on filling in data, including address, url, phone number, etc. for a list of businesses I have in a Google Sheet.

I have been on this site and others looking at scripts to call the Google Places API. I have figured out (I think) that I need to first get the Place_ID, and then I can call the API again to get all the details. I have copied and pasted a script off another answer on this forum, but it is hanging on line 8.

```
  return placeId.candidates[0].place_id;
```

in this line, it appears that the code that I copied is referencing "candidates", which I don't know what this is.

I'd like this to write the Place_id to a cell in the row with the other known data. For example: A2:T2 is all the known data. In U2 I placed `=locid(G2)` where G2 is the full address. I'd like (I think) U2 to get the place_id and then subsequent columns to receive the other requested data.

```
function locId(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDAI35g3ocior056QvNrjgY_lLs02Jkyg4';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  return placeId.candidates[0].place_id;
  Logger.log(placeId)
}


function GET_DETAILS(id) {
  var API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDAI35g3ocior056QvNrjgY_lLs02Jkyg4';
  var fields = 'name,rating,formatted_phone_number,formatted_address,photo';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + id + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY;

  if (id == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json).result;

  return [[ place.name,
            place.formatted_phone_number,
            place.rating,
            place.formatted_address,
           place.photo
          ]];
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "place_id" from undefined. (line 8).

I'm assuming the `undefined` here is the 'candidates'

I'm not sure how this code should be structured to achieve what I am looking for. 
I'm sure this is simple, as being a total hack noob, I have only a little understanding of what I am looking at. I appreciate your assistance in helping me understand how this works.

Comment: Ok, so I kept messing around with it and figured out that 'candidates' is the first layer in the JSON that the API returns. It appears now that the ```[0]``` is the issue. When I take the ```[0]``` out it no longer returns an error, but does not return the place_id either. When I look at the execution log, it does not show the ```(text)``` that is being run showing in the URL, which would explain why it is returning nothing.

Comment: So I have continued to mess with this. It appears that the parsing is not working properly. If I simply ```return JSON;``` It pulls the data through work. I'm just about to parse the JSON in Sheets with a formula and move on with my life. I still would like to make this work properly, as parsing a return with 1 entry is no big deal, but god help me on one with 100s or 1000s

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you find a proper solution for that?